# Need an Alert or Pop up or something before going to an Adult section of website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had found online at one time how to do this I think with javascript and that it had the page Faded out until someone clicked Yes or No and if you clicked no it took you back to the front of the site and if you clicked yes it unfaded the adult area? I dont actually need that but it would be nice if I could find that code again. I just need something to pop up on pages on the website which are adult oriented asking them if they are 18 years or older and if they hit yes it takes them to the site if they hit no then it doesn't take them to the site. Thank you for any help you can give me. I've tried looking online and haven't found what I am looking for.

Comment: set a cookie or store a flag in localstorage and check if the flag is not set show the popup , else proceed to the site.

Comment: Vigikaran wouldn't people with Cookies turned off be able to bypass that ? Im still learning so if thats not the case sorry.

Comment: in that case you need to show the pop everytime when the user visit the page. all the client side storage can be editable by user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `confirm()` method, if you are not worried about the design.

```
let userResponse = confirm("Content For Adults. Do you want to proceed?");

if(userReponse == true){ //just "userResponse" would do, but de " == true " serves more for didatics
 //Redirect to content
}else{
 //Redirects to homepage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make a Simple CSS window that popped up when you went to the page itself. It would ask you to confirm that you were 18 or over if you clicked yes the window went away and you were allowed on the site and if you clicked no then it sends you back to the main site. I modified the window so it covered the full page and it seems like it also makes it so the person can't bypass the confirmation window. Thank you all for the help which actually teaches me more stuff to add to my notes.